# Proof of Stakeのコンセンサスアルゴリズムで、validatorを選ぶノードは分散的に存在しているのでしょうか？

Tags: アルゴリズム, ethereum

Proof of Stakeのコンセンサスアルゴリズムは、Stakeしているコインの量に応じてランダムにValidatorが選ばれ、ValidatorがTransactionを承認します。不正するとStakeしているコインが没収されてしまうため、不正をしないモチベーションが働きます。そのため、51%攻撃は実質不可能とされています。
色々な資料を読んでいても、Validatorの選び方については言及されていますが、Validatorの選ぶノードに関しては言及しているのを見かけません。
もし、Validatorの選ぶノードがすべてハッキングされて、ハッカーが保有するValidatorのみが選ばれてしまえば、不正なtransactionを承認されてしまうことになります。

私はValidatorの選ぶノードについて下記の内容について疑問に思っています。

- Validatorの選ぶノードは分散されたノードなのか？それとも、中央集権的なノードなのか？
- もし分散されたノードならば、

  - どうやって選び方に同期をとっているのか？
  - Validatorの選ぶノードになるための条件はなにか？
- もし中央集権的なノードならば、

  - そのノードはどこで動いているのか？
  - なぜハッキングされないのか？

またはなにか参考になる記事でもあれば、ぜひ教えてください。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。